# charge distribution when enclosed and connected by wire

Tags: electrostatics

When a metal sphere with charge q is enclosed by a spherical conducting shell, and both are connected by a wire, Whole charge q will reside on the outer shell. **Why does this happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reason this is the right configuration using the following facts:

1. Any conductors that are touching have the same potential, otherwise charge would flow to the region with the lowest potential
2. The charge on a metal sphere is always located on the edge, in a spherical shell.
3. The field produced by a spherical shell containing charge $q$ at distance $r$ is $$\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}{\hat r}$$
   outside the shell and $\vec 0$ inside the shell. This last fact is the most important here. Note that the charge always distributes itself equally over the entire shell.
4. Because of 3. the potential of a spherical shell is $$\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$$
   outside the shell and has a constant value inside the shell, namely $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}$ with $R$ the radius of the shell.

Let's look at the initial configuration, before the wire is connected. Let's call the radius of the inner sphere $R_1$ and the radius of the outer sphere $R_2$. The potential energy at $R_1$ is equal to $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R_1}$ because of (2.). The potential at $R_2$ is $\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R_2}$, this is less than the potential at $R_1$ since the radius is larger. Now imagine you remove all the charge from the inner shell and add some charge to the outer shell, this will make the potential at $R_1$ and $R_2$ the same. This is because the outer shell induces no electric field inside (3.) so it takes no extra work to move from $R_2$ to $R_1$.

If we now add some charge again to the inner shell the potential will increase by some amount, the potential at $R_2$ will also increase but less than the inner shell. So this means that if there is any charge on the inner shell, the potential of the inner shell will be higher than on the outer shell; so charge will flow towards the outer shell. The only stable configuration is all the charge on the outer shell.

Comment: My confusion is ,will hole charge on inner sphere will go on outer shell? otherwise if the inner shell has any charge left, it will not be at the same potential, am I right? but In this video it is said that the inner shell will also have some charge after they are at same potential

Answer (score 0):

You can understand this  if you ponder over the fact that whenever two charges bodies are connected with conducting wires charges residing on them redistribute themselves so as to make the potential of the conductors equal. When the charged sphere and the shell are connected  assume that some charge say  *X*  flows to the outer shell . Then using this set up equations for the potential of the two objects and equate them . When you solve the equations you will get the value of *X* to be  equal to Q itself . Where Q denotes the initial charge on the sphere

Comment: I found this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Va_h-RuV1RM  Here it is shown that the whole charge will not reside to outer sphere

Comment: Bro listen I never said that in all cases such a thing would happen that all the charge goes to the outer surface . What I said  meant that a quantity of charge flows between the two conductors so as to equalise their electrosatic potential.